# Need to move the dryer vent up by 3ft

Tags: hvac, drywall, washing-machine, venting, laundry

I just bought a stacking washer/dryer machine and I need to relocate my floor dryer vent by  3ft above the floor so that I can push my machine all the way against the wall.  This will give me about 7in of extra space in my laundry room.   My floor vent is behind the wall and vent through the roof.  It is 10x3.25 size rectangular tube and it's pretty much stuck to a stud.

One option is to cut the rectangular vent tube at a 3ft location and add a stack boot.  But I am not sure how to seal it since the stud is right next to the tube and no space for me to wrap the tape around to seal it.

I think the easiest way is to punch a hole at 3ft location and add a 4" opening for the dryer. And seal off the floor vent.  This will be much less cutting and easier to seal. However, this setup creates T or Y like connection. Dryer air will flow in two directions, up and down.   Air flows downward by 3ft but it's blocked at the floor.  And also flows upward to the roof (25ft) and exit. Is this an OK setup or will create issues?

Thank you so much in advance for any advice.

[image: dryer vent]

Comment: It sounds like you know but i have to ask. Are you positive the rectangle duct in the stud bay is your dryer vent?

Answer (score 2):

It'd be better if you modify the duct.  A dryer vent that fills up with lint is a serious fire hazard and even if you're sure you'll clean it regularly, the next homeowner may not.

You can find a lot of videos on Youtube about how to work with that kind of ducting.

I'm not sure if you'll need any materials; it may be possible to re-configure what you already have.  But if you do need anything, the HVAC section of your local home improvement store should be your first stop.

Answer (score 0):

Air flow should not be a problem, With the old inlet sealed air pressure will ensure that it flows correctly.

more worrying is that this stub will trap lint.

Comment: Thank you Jasen.  I plan to use this to add a 4" opening 
 https://www.homedepot.com/p/Master-Flow-4-in-Air-Tite-Take-Off-ATTO4/204151837   and use this to cap the floor opening.https://www.homedepot.com/p/Master-Flow-4-in-Round-Duct-Cap-DC4/100396932  Plan to use plenty of sealant tapes ensure a tight seal.

Comment: I will make sure that I clean out the vent for any lint build-ups.  I just cleaned it out professionally because my dryer died (burned) due to a lint build up.   I plan to check it frequently. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

[image]

"It sounds like you know but I have to ask. Are you positive the rectangle duct in the stud bay is your dryer vent?"

This photo shows where the dryer vent is connected.  I am pretty sure it's the dryer vent.  It gets warm when the dryer is running.

I am planning to add [a quick vent connector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0028BAAWW) at 3ft above the vent so that I can have a straight connection to the vent system.  It will allow me to push the laundry unit fully against the wall without interfering with the vent operation.
I will try to search Youtube for working on a rectangular type vent but  I am not sure if I want to do this now. Perhaps, after all the remodeling is done.  Thank you all for your very helpful suggestions and advice.  THANK YOU

Comment: This should be edited into your question not placed in the answer box